# How to Retrieve the Coordinates for the wall Openings

Tags: revit-api, revit

I would like to retrieve the coordinates (points) of a door which resides in a wall. 
I am getting the openings as below. Also, I am having the width. How can I find out the end point of the opening. Also, is there any easy other way to achieve this?

var openings = WallSelected.FindInserts(true, true, true, true);

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options, here are two:

1. Each insert, if cast to a family instance, will have a location point in its location property.  You can find that point, relate it to the direction of the wall (determined from the wall location line) and apply 1/2 the width in each direction to find the extents of the opening.
2. Get the geometry of the wall and iterate the faces array to locate faces of the elements you are interested in.  You can use the location point of the insert to help narrow down the geometry search.  Once you have the faces associated with the opening, you will know the geometric extents of the opening as well.